# How to fix object flashing if planes are at same z value in ThreeJS?

Tags: three.js

I'd like to see later drawn object blocks previously drawn objects if they have the same z value. It is like z-index in css. How to achieve this?

There is a "CullFaceFrontBack" constant [here](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/constants/Renderer), but where do I set this constant? How do I know if it is in effect?

```
THREE.CullFaceNone
THREE.CullFaceBack
THREE.CullFaceFront
THREE.CullFaceFrontBack
```

Here is the code I used to generate the offset position:

```
    for(let i = 0; i < SQUARE_COUNT; i++ ) {

        offsets.push( Math.random() - 0.5, Math.random() - 0.5, 0); // z is same for all offsets
        colors.push( Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random() );
    }
```

The reason I am trying to cull is because my render is like this, it is basically 1000 square rendered at the same Z axis, x and y are random. They all keep flashing when rotating, no rotating no flashing. I think the problem is GPU is trying to rendering one on top of another and trying to blend and re-render. But I could be wrong, please correct me.

[image]

Comment: "Correct me if I am wrong, I think cull means not rendering surface that is block by other surfaces in front it" -- no, cull means "don't draw the surface if's facing away from the viewer".  Nothing to do with whether there's something in front of it or not.

Comment: BTW I don't know about this library in particular, but I know 3D rendering.  In order to get rid of the unwanted artifacts -- which aren't a surprise -- first explain what you WANT to see.

Comment: I like to see later drawn object overrides (blocking) previous drawn objects if they have the same z value, it is like z-index in css. Question content updated.

Comment: I assume that 3rd parameter, which you have set to `0`, is the z value?  Try setting it to `i`, not `0`.

Comment: @user2740650 I can see your method works, but if I really want to set all z to 0, since I want them to look like the same size from camera, is there a way to do it?

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case I'd suggest a very tiny difference in the z value, so instead of supplying `i`, try supplying `i * 0.01` so that they are only very slightly closer.  Try playing with that `0.01` constant since I just picked it out of the air.

Comment: I summarized this exchange as an answer.  Please accept it if it helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

No, "cull" means to render only polygons that are facing a certain direction (usually, away).  It doesn't have anything to do with other objects being in front of it.

You said you want squares added later in the loop to be on top visually.  Since GPU-based rendering usually only cares about depth, not order, you'd have to add a z value to tell it to render them in front of the other squares. To do that, specify the z value as the third parameter where you have zero, i.e.

`offsets.push( Math.random() - 0.5, Math.random() - 0.5, i * 0.01);`

The constant `0.01` might be something you have to experiment with.

Answer (score 0):

I think those constants are now obsolete, I get this error when trying to set them:

> THREE.WebGLRenderer: .shadowMap.cullFace has been removed. Set
>   Material.shadowSide instead.

Try this:

```
const mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
```

nb: you'll need a light if you use Phong or Lambert